# Unreliable action removeObserver: iPhone Video playback

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am first doing add observer call

followed by remove observer in the notification function.

I am certain that removerObserver is called as I see it on the stack
However, the app crashes as if a bad memory reference is left over in the notification center.

I think there are 2 possiblities

1. I am hitting an apple bug
2. My sequence of invocation is wrong

Here is my code from playvideo function

```
 //Initialize a MPMoviePlayerController object with the movie.
 moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector: @selector(movieReadyPlayMovieNow:) 
               name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification object:nil];  


 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector: @selector(moviePlayBackFinished:) 
              name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
```

Here is Notification called when the movie is done preloading

```
- (void) movieReadyPlayMovieNow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    @try {
        if(moviePlayer != nil){   
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                 name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification  
                 object:moviePlayer];    
             [moviePlayer play];  

        } 
   }
   catch(id exception) {
       NSLog(@"Error playing.");
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're registering from `name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification` notifications from any (nil) object:

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieReadyPlayMovieNow:) name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification **object:nil**];

But you're de-registering specifically from the `moviePlayer` object.

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification **object:moviePlayer**];

Try either registering for the object `nil` on both, or `moviePlayer` on both and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a notification while running inside a notification may be a Bad Thing.

Try removing the notification in a separate method and invoking that method with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay using a zero delay, or with performSelectorOnMainThread:. Either of these will finish the current run loop and then will execute the removeObserver method outside the notification call.